# MongoDB connection failed in ubuntu container

Tags: mongodb, docker, shell, dockerfile

I create a docker container with the base image ubuntu:18.04 and installed MongoDB using the shell in this container. Now, I commit and export this container and use this container image as a base image in a new container in which I need the MongoDB status as running for further process. I am using `Dockerfile` for both containers.
First `Dockerfile`is :

```
#getting base image ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils wget gnupg gnupg2 curl

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

CMD ["echo","Create base image"]
```

After building this Dockerfile, I accessed shell installed MongoDB, created a new db and collection, commit and export in the tar file.

Next, I import this tar file as image `mongoubuntu:1.0`
Now, I create another Dockerfile in which I want to run some commands which need MongoDB status as running.
The second `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM mongoubuntu:1.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo && apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get install -y wget     #install wget lib
COPY . /
RUN chmod +x /genesis.sh
RUN /genesis.sh
RUN chmod +x /wallet.sh
RUN /wallet.sh >> /config.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
CMD ["echo","Install EOS Complete"]
```

When I run this as `docker build -t eossample:1.5 .` It gets build successful. When I check the bash shell for the newly created container using this image, MongoDB is not running. If I manually start MongoDB it shows running status. Please help. How could I start MongoDB from DockerFile?

Comment: Hello, can you explain why not using official image of MongoDB ? Why are you starting from ``FROM ubuntu:18.04`` ? I suggest you start with https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo as ``FROM mongo:latest``. The mongo instance is automatically launch when you'll run the image.

You should let mongo in it's own container and put your 'app' in another one. Then you may be able to make both communicate.

Comment: Hi, I tried `FROM mongo:latest`, run the image and use this image in another Dockerfile. But still, I am getting MongoDB connection failes.

Comment: @Varsh do you start a container with `docker run`/`docker container run`? Or are you just building images? You need to start a container, e.g. `docker container run --rm -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -p 27017:27017 mongo`.

Comment: Yes, I started the container for every image I use.